# android take photo, compress and save in sdcard camera (FATAL EXCEPTION) Null pointer

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception, compression, native

Can anybody tell me why am I getting FATAL Error, when trying to use the native camera. Am new in Android programming and constantly facing trouble in implementing a fast, easy, flexible and reliable "Camera app". I have already tried a lot of things. But, somehow, something goes wrong and either the app crashes or it takes time (the app freezes).

```
package com.ambalika.efficientimageloading;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BitmapActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btnClickImage, btnFromGallery, btnSend, btnCancel;
    private ListView listView;
    private ImageView imgView;

    private ImageUriDatabase database;
    private ImageListAdapter adapter;
    private ImageLoadingUtils utils;

    private Cursor cursor;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> memoryCache;

    private final int REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY = 01;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE_CLICK_IMAGE = 02;

    String TAG = "Bitmap Activity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bitmap);

        database = new ImageUriDatabase(this);
        utils = new ImageLoadingUtils(this);
        int cachesize = 60*1024*1024;

        memoryCache  = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cachesize){
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
                 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=12){
                     return value.getByteCount();
                 }
                 else{
                     return value.getRowBytes()*value.getHeight();
                 }
            }
        };
        initViews();

        cursor = database.getallUri();
        adapter = new ImageListAdapter(this, cursor, true);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initViews() {
         btnClickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickImage);
         btnFromGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFromGallery);
         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

         btnClickImage.setOnClickListener(this);
         btnFromGallery.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        memoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return memoryCache.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bitmap, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.btnClickImage:
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CLICK_IMAGE);
         }
         break;
         case R.id.btnFromGallery :
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             intent.setType("image/*");
             startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY);
         }
         break;
         }

    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        imgView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dlgImageView);
        btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnSend = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, final Dialog dialog, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (id){
        case 1:
            if(bundle != null){
                final String filePath = bundle.getString("FILE_PATH");
                imgView.setImageBitmap(utils.decodeBitmapFromPath(filePath));

                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        database.insertUri(filePath);
                        cursor = database.getallUri();
                        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);   
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        memoryCache.evictAll();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY:             
                new ImageCompressionAsyncTask(true).execute(data.getDataString());

                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CLICK_IMAGE:
                new ImageCompressionAsyncTask(false).execute(data.getDataString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageCompressionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        private boolean fromGallery;

        public ImageCompressionAsyncTask(boolean fromGallery){
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + ": ImageCompressionAsyncTask: Constructor initiated");

            this.fromGallery = fromGallery;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + ": doInBackground: " + params[0]);

            String filePath = compressImage(params[0]);
            return filePath;
        }

        public String compressImage(String imageUri) {
            Log.d(TAG, TAG + ": compressImage: Compression started" + imageUri);

            String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;                      
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);

            int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
            int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
            float maxHeight = 816.0f;
            float maxWidth = 612.0f;
            float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
            float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

            if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
                if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                    imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                    actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                    actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                    imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                    actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
                } else {
                    actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;     

                }
            }

            int inSampleSize = 1;
            try {
                inSampleSize = utils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

            try{    
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryError exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
            try{
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryError exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
            float ratioY = actualHeight / (float)options.outHeight;
            float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
            float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

            Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
            scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
            canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth()/2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));


            ExifInterface exif;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                }
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            String filename = getFilename();
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return filename;

        }

        private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
            Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                return contentUri.getPath();
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                return cursor.getString(idx);
            }
        }

        public String getFilename() {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            return uriSting;

        }



        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {            
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(fromGallery){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("FILE_PATH", result);
                showDialog(1, bundle);
            }
            else{
                database.insertUri(result);
                cursor = database.getallUri();
                adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            }
        }

    }

    class ImageListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        private ImageLoadingUtils utils;

        public ImageListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean autoRequery) {
            super(context, cursor, autoRequery);
            utils = new ImageLoadingUtils(context);             
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            loadBitmap(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageUriDatabase.PATH_NAME)), holder.imageView, context);

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            view.setTag(holder);
            return view;
        }

        public void loadBitmap(String filePath, ImageView imageView, Context context) {
            if (cancelPotentialWork(filePath, imageView)) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(filePath);
                if(bitmap != null){
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                else{
                final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(context.getResources(), utils.icon, task);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
                task.execute(filePath);
                }
            }
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            ImageView imageView;
        }

        class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

            private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

            public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
            super(res, bitmap);
            bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
            }

            public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
            return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
            }
        }

        public boolean cancelPotentialWork(String filePath, ImageView imageView) {

            final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

            if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final String bitmapFilePath = bitmapWorkerTask.filePath;
            if (bitmapFilePath != null && !bitmapFilePath.equalsIgnoreCase(filePath)) {
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
               if (imageView != null) {
                   final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                   if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                   final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                   return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
                   }
                }
                return null;
            }

        class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
            public String filePath;

            public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView){
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                filePath = params[0];
                Bitmap bitmap = utils.decodeBitmapFromPath(filePath);
                addBitmapToMemoryCache(filePath, bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }
                if(imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null){
                    final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
                if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Complete error log:

```
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:468)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:458)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:430)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at com.ambalika.efficientimageloading.BitmapActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.getRealPathFromURI(BitmapActivity.java:328)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at com.ambalika.efficientimageloading.BitmapActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.compressImage(BitmapActivity.java:221)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at com.ambalika.efficientimageloading.BitmapActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.doInBackground(BitmapActivity.java:214)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at com.ambalika.efficientimageloading.BitmapActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.doInBackground(BitmapActivity.java:1)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-06 05:29:40.122: E/AndroidRuntime(1096):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you please point out the line number 328 in your activity?

Comment: you are passing null value to this method getRealPathFromURI()

Comment: Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);

This is the line number 328, but it looks like, its comes NULL, because the doInBackground has NullPointer in the params

Comment: No solution/suggestion yet. Anybody, who can help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your cursor is null. Try using this in your getRealPathFromURI function:

```
Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(contentURI);
try {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
} catch (Exception e) {
    filePath = selectedImage.getPath();
}
return filePath;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. I shall try out your suggestion.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as mentioned above, but still getting the same NullPointer error. The probable reason for this, is that, we are not getting any value in the params of doInBackground method.